# PyQt6 - Automatically Close QMessageBox after N seconds

Tags: python, qt, pyqt6

I am trying to make a QMessageBox automatically close after **3** seconds in PyQt6

Here is my minimum reproducible example which does not work:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMessageBox
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        msgBox = QMessageBox.about(self, 'hello', 'Need to automatically close after 3 seconds')
        QTimer.singleShot(3000, lambda : msgBox.done(0))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = App()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

If I start the QTimer before I call the QMessageBox it seems to work but isntead crashes the program

Comment: I will create a separate QThread for the QMessageBox and end the thread after 3s.

Comment: thats clever. i will try it

Comment: No. That's not clever. It's wrong. Widgets are not thread safe and cannot be created in separate threads.

Comment: @zeroalpha don't use the static functions, create a full instance.

Comment: @musicamante Qt does not seem to provide any easy way to create manually and instance of About dialog. It is only available via the static function. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager Are you talking about the "About Qt" dialog? Because the normal `about()` static has nothing special, except for the way it finds the window icon.

Comment: @musicamante Well, as you say, the normal About dialog has something special - the icon. One would need to implement it by hand. That is unnecessary extra work.

Comment: I don't see that as an extreme amount of "extra work". With 2-3 lines you can easily create the same result, since the icon is just the parent's (or the app) `windowIcon()`.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: the first solution which I proposed below works only on macOS, I have however added yet another one, which works on all platforms.)

The problem is that `QMessageBox::about()` returns `None` which is then assigned to `msgBox` variable. Subsequently the lambda crashes after 3 secs because `None` does not have `done()` member.

Unfortunately Qt/PyQt API does not provide any easy way to obtain the About dialog created with `QMessageBox.about()`. It also does not provide any easy way to create an instance of About dialog manually.

So if you want to really obtain the About dialog, you need to resort to a few little hacks. See the code:

```
# Note: this works only on macOS

import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMessageBox
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer, Qt

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        QMessageBox.about(self, 'hello', 'Need to automatically close after 3 seconds')
        msgBox = self.findChild(QMessageBox)
        msgBox.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_DeleteOnClose, False)
        QTimer.singleShot(3000, lambda: msgBox.deleteLater())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = App()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The magic is in `msgBox = self.findChild(QMessageBox)`. But beware it is based on assumption that the `App` instance has no other child message box than the created about dialog. So if you change you code someday in the future, and this assumption gets violated, then the code as is will stop working.

There are however two more problems with your code: if the user clicks on button "Ok" before the three seconds elapsed, the dialog is closed and deleted. And then the lambda crashes too because it would try to call `done()` on deleted object. There is yet another hack to prevent this. See the line `msgBox.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_DeleteOnClose, False)` which causes that when the user closes the dialog, it does not get deleted. But we want the dialog to be finally deleted and not to hang around (though hidden) till the program ends (or `App` instance is deleted, as it is its child). So when the 3 secs ellapse, we delete it manually using `deleteLate()` in the lambda.

PS: There are more other problems in that code, for example you do not show your main `App` widget, so the program keeps hanging after the About dialog gets closed and you have no way to close the program. But it is a different story and it would be a different question. You are free to solve this problem yourself.

PPS: What you seem to do is actually abusing a normal About dialog. Maybe what you are looking for is `QSplashScreen`.

PPPS: As discussed in comments below, the solution above does work only on macOS because on other platforms, `QMessageBox::about()` blocks the code execution until the dialog is close dby the user. In order to make it work on all platforms, the hacks must be much more complex.

```
# Note: this works on all platforms

import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMessageBox
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._aboutMsgBoxClosed = False
        QTimer.singleShot(3000, lambda: self._closeMsgBox())
        QMessageBox.about(self, 'hello', 'Need to automatically close after 3 seconds')
        if not self.findChild(QMessageBox):
            self._aboutMsgBoxClosed = True

    def _closeMsgBox(self):
        if not self._aboutMsgBoxClosed:
            msgBox = self.findChild(QMessageBox)
            if msgBox:
                msgBox.deleteLater()
                self._aboutMsgBoxClosed = True

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = App()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Explanation: we must dispatch closing **before** opening the dialog. But we must ensure that it gets deleted only if the user dad not already closed it. That is why we introduce variable `_aboutMsgBoxClosed`, its aim is also to protect against potential closing of some possible message boxes other than About dialog. But as you can see, these hacks and logic are quite complicated so it may be better to create an instance of the About dialog yourself, manually and work with the instance instead of calling the static method `about()`.

Comment: Just wondering: Have you tried using [QApplication.activeWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qapplication.html#activeWindow), instead of `findChild`, to obtain the "about" dialog? According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmessagebox.html#about), the "about" dialog is modal, except on MacOS.

Comment: @djvg yes, I tried`activeWindow()` as the first possible solution. But in the code as it is written it did not work and returned `None`. The problem seems to be that the code is called before the application event loop starts processing events. The window to be activated obviously needs some events to be processed first. The `findChild()` therefore seems a little bit more robust solution. Btw. it does not matter whether the dialog is modal or not.

Comment: But that's not valid. `QMessageBox.about` is blocking, like all its other static functions. So, the timer will be useless, `findChild` will therefore return `None` and `setAttribute` will crash.

Comment: @musicamante You are right. The version which I presented here works well on macOS (where I had tested it) but unfortunately not on Windows (as I have tested just now). The docs however do not mention the code-blocking nature, it only mentions application modality which does necessarily imply blocking... But yes, it actually is blocking on Windows. The docs should be more specific on this. Moreover I find this really strange design in Qt... having it it non-blocking on one platform and blocking on other platforms... This makes it hard to write a robust crossplatform code. :(

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager You're right too, the docs only mention that on macOS the message box is modeless, so I assume that they imply it has no event loop, hence the difference in behavior: I just checked the sources and `show()` is used only on macOs, while all other platforms use `exec()`.

Comment: @musicamante Yes, this surprised me a bit, I did not expect such a difference among platforms. If it was modeless on macOS and modal (but nonblocking the execution) on other platforms, it would be fine, because the rest of the code can be unified for all platforms. But the way it is implemented, it is very hard to write one code because in one case the execution continues and in other it halts till the dialog is closed.

Anyway, I added a warning to my answer that it only works on macOS. That was a good lesson for me too.

Comment: @musicamante I finally managed to work out a somewhat hackish solution which should work on all platforms, see the updated answer. But it is quite ugly. It seems it is really easier to create the message box instance manually... :)

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager Yes, creating the QMessageBox instance is usually preferable, but there's still another possibility. See my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

While the [other proposed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75833761/2001654) works fine on macOS, it will not work for all other platforms, for which the static functions are always blocking: on macOS the dialog is modeless and shown asynchronously, while in other platforms the dialog's `exec()` is internally called and the function doesn't return until the dialog is closed.

For proper cross platform compatibility, the solution is to just use a standard instance of QMessageBox. The only thing the `about()` static function actually does is to set the icon based on the [`windowIcon`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowIcon-prop), so we just need to implement that part as Qt does in C++:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.button = QPushButton('Show message box')
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.showMessageBox)

    def showMessageBox(self):
        msgBox = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Icon.Information, 
            'hello', 'Need to automatically close after 3 seconds', 
            parent=self)
        msgBox.setWindowFlags(
            Qt.WindowType.Dialog
            | Qt.WindowType.WindowTitleHint 
            | Qt.WindowType.WindowSystemMenuHint 
            | Qt.WindowType.WindowCloseButtonHint
        )
        icon = msgBox.windowIcon()
        msgBox.setIconPixmap(icon.pixmap(icon.actualSize(QSize(64, 64))))
        msgBox.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        closeTimer = QTimer(msgBox, singleShot=True, interval=3000, 
            timeout=msgBox.close)
        closeTimer.start()
        msgBox.exec()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = App()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

But that's not very elegant nor convenient or readable.

A possible alternative solution is to create a custom object that acts as a "watcher" on the QApplication instance right before calling `about()`, wait for the first `Show` event for a QMessageBox object, and automatically create a timer for it.

```py
class MessageBoxCloser(QObject):
    def __init__(self, timeout=3000):
        app = QApplication.instance()
        super().__init__(app)
        app.installEventFilter(self)
        self.timeout = timeout

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if isinstance(obj, QMessageBox) and event.type() == event.Type.Show:
            timer = QTimer(obj, singleShot=True, interval=self.timeout, 
                timeout=obj.close)
            timer.start()
            QApplication.instance().removeEventFilter(self)
            self.deleteLater()
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


# ...

class App(QWidget):
    # ...
    def showMessageBox(self):
        MessageBoxCloser()
        QMessageBox.about(self, 'hello', 
            'Need to automatically close after 3 seconds')
```